# Run a parallell process in linux

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I have 9 executable and a main process that needs to be running in parallell. (The main process is a test program which runs test against the 9 executables that needs to be running in the background).

Running on Linux!

The main process (a c++ program) that needs to start the 9 executables can NOT wait for the executables to be finished since they need to be running in parallell.

I have tried the following:

1. Calling system(/path_to_app1/app1); from my main program. This will just run app1 in the console forever an never continue with my main test program.
2. fork() with wait(). This solution is dependent on that the parent (main program) can wait until the child (app1 to app 9) is finish executing.

The best solution would be to use the spawnl(app1) which is a windows function to start the executable as a parallell process. But since I´m working on Linux this is no solution.

Tips and trixs?

Comment: As an advice, as you are using `c++` take a loot at pthreads or mpi/Openmp !!

Comment: Don't `wait()`after each fork, then.

Comment: @M.K Why would you suggest `pthreads` when C++ includes threads already?

Comment: You're right! Messed up! Wanted to say `threads`! But pthreads is quite used for linux, as he mentioned it, I thought it might also suit him @MarkSetchell

Comment: Do you have the code for the 9 executables?  I think you will benefit more by using C++ std::thread.